# Find $m$ and $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, exponentiation

Two finite sets have m and n elements. Thew total number of subsets of the first set is 56 more than the two total number of subsets of the second set. Find the value of $m$ and $n$.

> The equation to this question will be $2 ^ m$ - $2 ^ n = 56$.

But I don't know how to solve this equation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$2^m-2^n=56\Rightarrow 2^n(2^{m-n}-1)=56$

Look for factorization of $56$ into two numbers $a,b$ such that $a$ is even and $b$ is odd..

Can you conclude now?

Comment: ok then $2 ^ n$ will be even and $2 ^ {m - n} - 1$ will be odd??

Comment: @kool_kartikey : Yes... so then?

Comment: then n = 3 and m = 6...

Comment: @kool_kartikey : What else are you looking for?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/756235/evaluate-the-log-expression

Answer (score 2):

$$2^m - 2^n = 56\iff 2^n(2^{m-n} - 1) = 2^3\cdot 7 = 2^3( 2^3 - 1) = 56$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: min(n,m) is 8 as denominator of 56

Answer (score 0):

Let $k = m-3$ and $l=n-3$, then 
$$
2^k-2^l = 56/2^3 = 7.
$$
Now determine the values of $k$ and $l$.